# Get all the new users who submitted a request in 2016

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Is there a better way to scale the solution for this problem assuming the table has a billion rows of data. I am interested in getting all the new users who submitted a request in 2016.

Requests( request_id, request_day, user_id, userprofile_id )

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
  FROM requests
 WHERE EXTRACT( year FROM request_day ) = 2016
   AND user_id 
 NOT IN 
 ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id
     FROM requests 
    WHERE EXTRACT( YEAR FROM request_day ) <> 2016 
  );
```

Comment: No DISTINCT needed in the NOT IN sub-query. (Watch out for NULL's when doing NOT IN!!! NOT EXISTS is null safe.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following query to answer this question:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM requests
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(request_day) <> 2016 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

This will only return users who have requests appearing 2016 and no other year.

Comment: Can you tell me how does this query perform better and why?

Comment: Thanks for the soln Tim...but I am curious to know how scalability works..

Comment: Your current approach should work as far as I can tell by looking at it.  Can you check the performance of both approaches?  If yours runs substantially faster, I will delete this answer.

Comment: I think this approach should work better (aside from the equals sign should be replaced with THEN) because there is only one index scan whereas @Teja's approach requires two.

Comment: @JohnBingham This makes sense.  But the OP's subquery isn't correlated, which left me not seeing a compelling reason why either should be faster (until you explained further).

Answer (score 1):

Using `EXISTS` is usually faster than `IN`:

```
select distinct user_id
from requests r
where extract(year from request_day) = 2016
and not exists (
    select 1
    from requests
    where user_id = r.user_id
    and extract(year from request_day) <> 2016
    );
```